# Assigning values based on a small mask placed over a pixel

Tags: numpy

## The problem

I have a circular boolean mask of *arbitrary radius* (always perfectly symmetrical):

```
array([[False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then I have a large matrix of uint8, `image` and a pair in this matrix that can be any valid indice of it, `point`.

What I want to do is apply this mask over this point in the image such that I can essentially just place a circle at that point in the `image`.

This is quite straightforward to do in the middle of the image. You can just do:

```
image[point[0] - radius:point[0] + radius + 1, point[1] - radius:point[1] + radius + 1] = circle_mask
```

But naturally this doesn't handle bounds checking, which seems rather complicated in this case because I must ensure that the range of `image` that we're assigning to is the same size as the mask that is being assigned.

## Example

If `point` is `(1, 1)` and the radius of the circle mask was 2, then assuming that `image` was initially all zeros, it'd end up being:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  ... ,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  ... ,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  ... ,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  ... ,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  ... ,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  ... ,  0.]])
```

## My solution

I've come up with the following code that achieves what I want to do:

```
# Initialization of stuff so this is runnable
point = (1, 1)
radius = 2
image = np.zeros((10, 10))
x, y = np.ogrid[-radius : radius + 1, -radius : radius + 1]
circle_mask = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2

# My solution to the problem
image_min_row = max(point[0] - radius, 0)
image_min_col = max(point[1] - radius, 0)
image_max_row = min(point[0] + radius + 1, image.shape[0])
image_max_col = min(point[1] + radius + 1, image.shape[1])

mask_min_row = max(radius - point[0], 0)
mask_min_col = max(radius - point[1], 0)
mask_max_row = min(image.shape[0] - point[0] + radius, circle_mask.shape[0])
mask_max_col = min(image.shape[1] - point[1] + radius, circle_mask.shape[1])

temp_mask = circle_mask[mask_min_row:mask_max_row, mask_min_col:mask_max_col]
image[image_min_row:image_max_row, image_min_col:image_max_col][temp_mask] = 1
```

## My question

My solution feels really verbose. It took a lot of head-hurting arithmetic wrangling and had a couple of off-by-one bugs as I came up with it. I question if there's some easier way to do this. Some way that I can just take the mask, position it so that its center is over `point` and assign values based on that mask, ignoring out of bounds elements.

Does NumPy have a way to do this?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mask can be created directly in terms of the indices of the image, eliminating the bound checking:

```
x = np.arange(image.shape[0]) 
y = np.arange(image.shape[1])
image[np.add.outer((x-point[0])**2, (y-point[1])**2) <= radius**2] = 1
```

Here x, y are indices of the `image` array, and the condition under which assignment should happen is stated on the third line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using [Scipy's `binary-dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) to handle multiple points -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation as dilate

mask_mapped = np.zeros(image.shape,dtype=bool)
mask_mapped[points[...,0],points[...,1]] = 1
image[dilate(mask_mapped,circle_mask)] = 1
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1 : One point -

```
In [88]: points = np.array([1,1])

In [89]: image = np.zeros((10, 10))

In [90]: mask_mapped = np.zeros(image.shape,dtype=bool)
    ...: mask_mapped[points[...,0],points[...,1]] = 1
    ...: image[dilate(mask_mapped,circle_mask)] = 1
    ...: 

In [91]: print image
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Case #2 : Multiple points -

```
In [96]: points = np.array([[1,1],[7,3],[8,9]])

In [97]: image = np.zeros((10, 10))

In [98]: mask_mapped = np.zeros(image.shape,dtype=bool)
    ...: mask_mapped[points[...,0],points[...,1]] = 1
    ...: image[dilate(mask_mapped,circle_mask)] = 1
    ...: 

In [99]: print image
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

If you starting off from a `zeros` initialized array as image, you could simply use the dilated binary array as image, like so -

```
In [102]: print dilate(mask_mapped,circle_mask).astype(float)
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```